# from ctypes import dlsysm .... error says: can not import name dlsysm, help please?

Tags: ctypes, python-3.3

after downloading the package PyGF 0.3 in Ubuntu,  I run the command in python the following http://www.grammaticalframework.org/libpgf/pygf/tutorial.html

```
xavi@xavi-T12C:~/PyGF-0.3$ python3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:32:14) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pgf.pygf import *
>>> import_pgf('Food.pgf')
>>> parse('this wine is very expensive',lang='en_US')
pgf_new_parser (pgf/parser.c:908): precondition failed
    concr != NULL
Aborted (core dumped)
```

this assume you do have Food.pgf grammar file in working directory. The sentence "this wine is very expensive" is covered by that grammar. Now as here: `http://www.grammaticalframework.org/doc/gf-quickstart.html`, the .pgf file can be prepared from having Food.gf, FoodEng.gf, FoodIta.gf in one working directory, and use the command:

```
gf -make FoodIta.gf FoodEng.gf
```

This assume you have binary version of GF installed (very short to install).
This will write the Food.pgf file to be used in Python as in above code.

What is the error coming from? As in the tutorial its clearly said, it will work and parse the sentence. Although tutorial is with `Phrasebook.pgf` grammar, but assume that It work with all kinds of .pgf grammars. I tried with Phrasebook too (was big, the same error was there). Food is small, but good to try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `_ctypes.dlsym`, which takes a handle and a symbol name and either returns the address or raises `OSError` if the symbol isn't found.

**Edit Based on Revised Question**

To begin with make sure you're using Python 3.3. Some Linux distros default to 3.2. For example, Debian stable uses 3.2, but Debian testing has `python3.3`.

Download the source code for [libpgf](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/libpgf/). I used version 0.3. Untar the source and change to the directory. Then run `./configure`, `make`, and `ldconfig`:

```
libpgf-0.3$ ./configure
libpgf-0.3$ make
libpgf-0.3$ sudo make install
libpgf-0.3$ sudo ldconfig -v
```

This assumes your system is already configured for building from source and uses `sudo` for running commands as root. The latter enables libpgf and libgu to be installed to a system directory such as /usr/local/lib. Running `ldconfig` updates the library cache of the runtime linker ld.so. Refer to `man ldconfig` for a detailed explanation.

Next untar the PyGF source, change to its directory, and run the following:

```
PyGF-0.3$ python3.3 setup.py build
PyGF-0.3$ sudo python3.3 setup.py install
```

Comment: eryksun, I have installed the libpgf successfully from your mentioned code above. However when going the next step for PyGF as you said: PyGF-0.3$ python3.3 setup.py build, the problem came because my default python is 2.7 version in linux. Although I installed python 3.3.2 but the default path is: /opt/python3.3/bin/python3, in order to enter to python 3.3 version in terminal. So considering that, I tried to do this instead: PyGF-0.3$ /opt/python3.3/bin/python3 setup.py build but it doesnt work either.

Comment: `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3 setup.py build` followed by `sudo /opt/python3.3/bin/python3 setup.py install` should work. It will make it easier if you add a symbolic link on the sudo `PATH` (look at `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`). For example to add a link to `/usr/local/bin`, use `sudo ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.3`.

Comment: eryksun, I got stuck when doing this setup for pyGF, problem came because "NO module setuptools found", for that i installed distribute, but while installing distribute problem came "NO module zlib found", and while installing zlib the following issues arises http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901775/error-when-processing-deb-zlib-package-in-uduntu   I suppose you have installed previously, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're using Ubuntu "precise" (12.04), which already has zlib (the actual system library) installed. It doesn't have a Python 3.3 package, which is in newer releases of Ubuntu such as ["quantal" (12.10)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/python3.3). So you built or dpkg installed a local copy of Python 3.3 in /opt that doesn't have the Python zlib extension module needed by the setuptools installer. Is that right?